# Creating login Form In C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a sign in form and when user write user and pass i want to find the RoleId which can tell us this user should sign in as operator or manager or any thing else but i can't find how to read Roleid from table?

```
private void btn_sin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt_pass.Text);
            System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 h = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
            byte[] hashed = h.ComputeHash(b);

            var txtEncrptedPass = Convert.ToBase64String(hashed);

            var query = Obj_db.Tbl_Login.Where(s => s.UserName == txt_Username.Text & s.Password == txtEncrptedPass).ToList();

            if (query.Count != 0)
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                var m =Convert.ToInt32( query.Select(a => a.RoleId.Value).ToList());
                if (m==1)
                {
                    Main_form main = new Main_form();
                       main.Show();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" SignIn error! \n username or password entered incorrectly");
            }
```

this code show me cast error!!

Comment: so you are trying to convert a list to int32? i guess it should be `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: What is the error, if you are getting one?  Also in your query you are using single & ishould be &&.

Comment: Please provide more error details. In line ```var m = ...``` you are trying to convert a list into a single Int32 value. Consider adding ```First()``` after ```Select``` statement

Comment: Use `First()` instead of `ToList()` here `var m = Convert.ToInt32( query.Select(a => a.RoleId.Value).First());`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a list to long.

What you should do it to convert a single value using `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`.

With out testing it, change this:

```
var m = Convert.ToInt32(query.Select(a => a.RoleId.Value).ToList());
```

to

```
var m = Convert.ToInt32(query.Select(a => a.RoleId.Value).First());
```

It should solve your issue.